# Mullvad VPN WireGuard several interfaces on the same machine

Tags: linux, networking, vpn, python, wireguard

Not sure what I am trying to do is even possible. I am trying to create a web crawler with about 20 threads and I am trying to route each thread requests (using python `requests`) through a different WireGuard configuration (thus a different external IP)

I am currently using Windows but I don't mind installing Linux if it will make things easier

I found this thread which is the first step - https://stackoverflow.com/a/48997550 - basically using `curl` and selecting which interface to send the requests through.

Another solution I can use is just add 20 different virtual network devices to my VM and give each of them a different WireGuard configuration in my router - this may actually work - but I thought there might be an easier solution

Thanks

Comment: You say *"Another solution I can use"* ... implies that there is already a solution, what's wrong with that solution that you want "another" one?

Comment: What didn't work for you w/ several wireguards? https://serverfault.com/questions/1105756/wireguard-single-server-with-multiple-interfaces